# How to parse json format String in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

How to parse following json string in java. I would like to retrieve one by one.

```
{"IN1005*1001302*CWH":[{"qtyreceived":"5","itemcode":"1618306"},{"qtyreceived":"0","itemcode":"1618305"},{"qtyreceived":"0","itemcode":"288242"]}

Output can be 
head=IN1005*1001302*CWH
qtyreceived=5
itemcode:1618306
```

and so on

Please any one help me . I saw many examples but none of them are matching with my requirement. If you found solution for my question in another old post please let me know the post details and url

Comment: Have you tried googling "java parse json", or something similar?

Comment: No. My string doesn't have key in header so it is not at all similar to same .@ Chthonic Project. Please provide solution apt for me

Comment: Did you try doing this on your own yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could use GSON, check: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Gson for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest an algorithm:
1>Use any good REST API for java. I would suggest Apache Jersey.
2>You will have a Resource Layer in your application in which you will  recieve this JSON String from the other layer.
3> You can refer to the example as such in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html
4>Now the method that you are using will recieve the JSON String as argument. That can be consumed using @XMLROOTElement tag. 
Note: you need  to convert IN1005*1001302*CWH to IN10051001302CWH or something useful as it has special characters and you cannot create a java class.

```
 getJSON(WSObject object){}
```

Some description of your java object.

```
 @XmlRootElement
 WSObject{
     List<IN10051001302CWH>  jsonObject;
   }
```

And IN10051001302CWH would be again another object having properties that of your JSON properties which have same spelling :-

```
 @XmlRootElement
 IN10051001302CWH{

 private Long qtyrecieved;
 private Long  itemcode;      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Jackson, see this [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27263560/3496666) my answer for converting an object into json format.